# Why does a password guessing robot repeatedly test nonsense?

Tags: passwords, attacks

I log repeated invalid login attempts on a small custom made e-shop (no open source system is used). Last year, I started recording repeated failed logins from a single IP address. That's why I started logging the passwords that this IP address is trying to enter. It is clear that this is a robot (or human) that repeatedly (at relatively long intervals) tries to guess the password. It often tries for expected passwords like "admin", "editor", "123456", "domain name", etc. But I don't understand the other entries like gw7777777, etc. Why does it all start with "gw" and then a series of the same numbers, which is different in length? Could it be for some security reason? Can it help detect any type of vulnerability?

*In the following listing, I have replaced the real domain name with "domain_name". I also removed the times and the IP address.*

```
 10.11.2021     gw66666
 10.11.2021     admin
 10.11.2021     gw777777
 10.11.2021     123456
 10.11.2021     gw11111111
 10.11.2021     admin123
 10.11.2021     gw5555555
 10.11.2021     domain_name
 10.11.2021     gw666666666
 10.11.2021     admin@123
 10.11.2021     gw7777
 10.11.2021     pass
 10.11.2021     gw66666
 10.11.2021     12345
 10.11.2021     gw6666
 10.11.2021     1234
 10.11.2021     gw44444444
 10.11.2021     password
 10.11.2021     gw5555555555
 10.11.2021     domain_name123
 10.11.2021     gw222
 10.11.2021     123
 11.11.2021     gw55555555555
 11.11.2021     domain_name@123
 11.11.2021     gw888888
 11.11.2021     123456
 11.11.2021     gw111111
 11.11.2021     123123
 11.11.2021     gw555555555
 11.11.2021     admin1234
 11.11.2021     gw55555555
 11.11.2021     12345678
 11.11.2021     gw5555555
 11.11.2021     domain_name
 11.11.2021     gw8888888888
 11.11.2021     domain_name123
 11.11.2021     gw7777777777
 11.11.2021     adminadmin
 11.11.2021     gw777777777
 11.11.2021     123456789
 11.11.2021     gw666666666
 11.11.2021     Admin@123
 11.11.2021     gw7777777
 11.11.2021     admin88
 12.11.2021     gw33333333333
 12.11.2021     domain_name2017
 12.11.2021     gw6666
 12.11.2021     test
 6.12.2021      gw66666
 6.12.2021      admin
 6.12.2021      gw444444
 6.12.2021      123456
 6.12.2021      gw44444444
 6.12.2021      admin123
 7.12.2021      gw5555555
 7.12.2021      domain_name
 7.12.2021      gw888888888
 7.12.2021      admin@123
 7.12.2021      gw5555
 7.12.2021      pass
 7.12.2021      gw44444
 7.12.2021      12345
 7.12.2021      gw7777
 7.12.2021      1234
 7.12.2021      gw55555555
 7.12.2021      password
 7.12.2021      gw2222222222
 7.12.2021      domain_name123
 7.12.2021      gw666
 7.12.2021      123
 7.12.2021      gw88888888888
 7.12.2021      domain_name@123
 7.12.2021      gw555555
 7.12.2021      123456
 7.12.2021      gw555555
 7.12.2021      123123
 7.12.2021      gw888888888
 7.12.2021      admin1234
 7.12.2021      gw33333333
 7.12.2021      12345678
 7.12.2021      gw2222222
 7.12.2021      domain_name
 7.12.2021      gw4444444444
 7.12.2021      domain_name123
 7.12.2021      gw1111111111
 7.12.2021      adminadmin
 7.12.2021      gw333333333
 7.12.2021      123456789
 7.12.2021      gw6666666
 7.12.2021      admin88
 7.12.2021      gw33333333333
 7.12.2021      domain_name2017
 7.12.2021      gw6666
 7.12.2021      test
 7.12.2021      gw88888888
 7.12.2021      admin888
 7.12.2021      gw55555555
 7.12.2021      F*uckYou
 8.12.2021      gw1
 8.12.2021      1
 8.12.2021      gw5555555
 8.12.2021      Domain_name
 8.12.2021      gw55555555555
 8.12.2021      domain_name2016
 8.12.2021      gw77777
 8.12.2021      admin
 8.12.2021      gw111111
 8.12.2021      editor
 8.12.2021      gw55555555
 8.12.2021      password
 8.12.2021      gw88888888
 8.12.2021      admin123
 8.12.2021      gw444444
 8.12.2021      123456
 22.12.2021     gw777777
 22.12.2021     123456
 22.12.2021     gw77777777
 22.12.2021     password
 22.12.2021     gw3333333
 22.12.2021     domain_name
 6.1.2022       gw66666
 6.1.2022       admin
 6.1.2022       gw777777
 6.1.2022       editor
 7.1.2022       gw7777
 7.1.2022       test
 7.1.2022       gw8888888888888
 7.1.2022       administrator
 7.1.2022       gw55555555
 7.1.2022       admin123
 7.1.2022       gw111111111
 7.1.2022       admin@123
 7.1.2022       gw4444
 7.1.2022       test
 14.1.2022      gw6666666666666666
 14.1.2022      admin@domain_name.com
 14.1.2022      gw111111111
 14.1.2022      123456789
 14.1.2022      gw22222222
 14.1.2022      12345678
 14.1.2022      gw5555555
 14.1.2022      1234567
 14.1.2022      gw2222222
 14.1.2022      Domain_name
 14.1.2022      gw33333333333
 14.1.2022      Domain_name2021
 14.1.2022      gw444444444444
 14.1.2022      Domain_name@2021
 23.1.2022      Gw4444
 23.1.2022      test
 23.1.2022      Gw333
 23.1.2022      dev
 23.1.2022      Gw555555555
 23.1.2022      developer
 23.1.2022      Gw2222222
 23.1.2022      manager
 23.1.2022      Gw444444
 23.1.2022      editor
 28.1.2022      Gw3333333
 28.1.2022      domain_name
 28.1.2022      Gw333333
 28.1.2022      123456
 28.1.2022      Gw77777777
 28.1.2022      password
 28.1.2022      Gw555555555
 28.1.2022      admin2021
 28.1.2022      Gw444444444
 28.1.2022      admin2020
```

Comment: So, every other password makes sense to you except the `gw` passwords? So, your question is simply why `gw` is in their list to test?

Comment: From memory (I cannot confirm) the `gw####` has something to do with entering Chinese characters in an English format. If you google these strings, you will see that testing for `gw####` password strings is common, and that they are used as strings on Chinese-language sites, I cannot confirm the mapping, however.

Comment: ... because password brute forcing is run by script kiddies and people choose dumb passwords.

Comment: Maybe they confused it with a backend software that has gw###### as standard pw